# YAML anchors and override

Tags: yaml, yaml-anchors

I have a workflow with the following templates:

```
  templates:
  - name: main
    dag:
      tasks:
        - name: task1
          template: step1
        - name: task2
          template: step2

  - name: step1
    container:
      image: some-image
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command: [ bash ]
      args:
        - exit 0

  - name: step2
    container:
      image: some-image
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command: [ bash ]
      args:
        - exit 0
```

As shown, step1 and step2 are the same with a difference in their names.
I believe this duplication can be avoided by defining a single template and then using YAML anchors to reuse it.

```
  - name: $step
    container:
      image: some-image
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command: [ bash ]
      args:
        - exit 0

  - name: *step
```

My question is now regarding the name. How can the names be overriden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an anchor for the containers:

```
  - name: step1
    container: &container
      image: some-image
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command: [ bash ]
      args:
        - exit 0

  - name: step2
    container: *container
```

Answer (score 0):

As idea you can define some section with templates and then reuse these templates later like this

```
x-templates:
  - &step
    container:
      image: some-image
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command: [ bash ]
      args:
        - exit 0

steps:
  - name: step1
    <<: *step
  - name: step2
    <<: *step
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion, however, the wf cannot be submitted because a name is required for &step